# Non-primitive types to WorkManager Data

Tags: android, json, android-workmanager

In my project I use `WorkManager`. But I have a couple of questions.

1) How can I get a list of all running tasks at the current time?

2) How to transfer through `Data.Builder ()` not primitive data types? For example, a reference to an instance of the class Item:

```
public class Item {
private String path;
private String type;
private String name;
private int size;
private float radius;

public Item(String path, String type, String name, int size, float radius) {
    this.path = path;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
    this.radius = radius;
}}
```

Probably, it is necessary to serialize the transferred object to `JSON` and to transfer as `String`? Are there any other ways?

Comment: So what you're basically asking is how `WorkManager` works?

Comment: @HB.I understand how it works. How can I send this not primitive data types? I do not understand this.